# error XMLSchemaParseError while creating xsd schema in python lxml

Tags: python, xsd, lxml

I encoutered a problem with creating xsd schema in python using `lxml` library.
I have prepared an xsd schema file below (content was cut to the minimum)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified"
           version="2.4">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Bundeseinheitlicher Medikationsplan</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="MP">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Bundeseinheitlicher Medikationsplan</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="p" use="prohibited">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Name: Patchnummer</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                        <xs:maxInclusive value="99"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and when using `lxml` library to create xsd schema like this

```
from lxml import etree
with open('some_file.xsd') as schema_file:  # some_file.xsd is the file above
    etree.XMLSchema(file=schema_file)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi", line 87, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:197804)
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?)., line 16
```

But when doing this with the python standard library everything goes correct

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
with open('some_file.xsd') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
```

I played around a bit with the xsd file and discovered that when removing 
`use="prohibited"` from the attribiute element resolves the problem with `lxml` library but I need that property.

What can be the reason for that? Is something wrong with `lxml` library or rather the xml structure of above xsd is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but had me stumped for a bit.

Here's how I solved it.

```
schema_root = etree.parse(xsd_filename)
schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_root)
xml_parser = etree.XMLParser(schema=schema, no_network=False)
```

Then if you attempt to open it with something like

```
with open(xml_filename, 'rb') as f:
    etree.fromstring(f.read(), xml_parser)
```

You will only get actual `XMLSchemaErrors`

https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html

Comment: You linked XMLParser, the XMLSchema class doesn't have a 'no_network' member variable. https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/d3b9676f7fe6aaf388577c9a4c446bbe2f92c307/src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi#L45

Comment: @Addison thanks, you are correct, it is the parser that has that parameter. Updated.